# Return of None not expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small function as follows:

```
# Given the numerical value of a minute hand of a clock, return the number of degrees assuming a circular clock.
# Raise a ValueError for values less than zero or greater than 59.


def exercise_20(n):
    try:
        if n < 0 or n > 59:
            raise ValueError("Number supplied is less than 0 or greater than 59")
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)
    else:
        return n * 6


print(exercise_20(-15))
print(exercise_20(30))
print(exercise_20(75))
```

Here is the output:

```
Number supplied is less than 0 or greater than 59
None
180
Number supplied is less than 0 or greater than 59
None
```

Why am I returning 'None' when I strike an exception?

The function correctly prints the exception for the appropriate values and it prints the correct answer for a value within the correct range.

I don't understand why it also printing 'None' when it strikes an exception.

Comment: You don't return anything in the `except:` block, so it returns `None` by default. What are you expecting it to return instead?

Comment: What do you think it should be returning when the exception occurs, and why?

Comment: The *else* block is executed if no exception is raised in the *try* block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function should just raise the error. let the called to the catching:

```
def exercise_20(n):
    if n < 0 or n > 59:
        raise ValueError("Number supplied is less than 0 or greater than 59")
    return n * 6

for n in (-15, 30, 75, 30):
    print(f"{n=}:", end=" ")
    try:
        print(exercise_20(n))
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)
```

it will output:

```
n=-15: Number supplied is less than 0 or greater than 59
n=30: 180
n=75: Number supplied is less than 0 or greater than 59
n=30: 180
```

you code returns `None` because you do not have an explicit `return` statement after `print(ex)`. therefore python implicitly returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You try a block, if it fails your condition `if n < 0 or n > 59`, you raise. You then catch your raise and just log it. Then you return nothing. Catch and release is for fishing :).

```
def exercise_20(n):
    if n < 0 or n > 59:
      raise ValueError("Number supplied is less than 0 or greater than 59")
        
    return n * 6


print(exercise_20(-15))
print(exercise_20(30))
print(exercise_20(75))
```

You might be interested on this too: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187715/validation-of-the-input-parameter-in-caller-code-duplication#. When should you check for input conditions? Caller or callee?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `else:` only happens when there is no error. So when there is an error, it skips the `else` block (also skipping the `return` inside it), therefore returning `None`. Within the function definition, you print the error, and outside it, you print what is returned, causing the format to be

```
Error (if there is one)
Return value (None (if nothing is returned) or n*6)
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) have more information.